# Slice, Slice, Maybe

Tags: code-golf, string, python

Everyone loves slicing in python, as in `array[5]` to access the fifth element or `array[:5]` to access the zero through fourth element or `array[::-1]` to reverse an array. However, these all have seemingly distinct notations. When and where should the colons and integers be placed?

## Task

Your task is to change any valid slice syntax into a slice with as many colons and integers as possible. To help with that, we will make some definitions. Valid slice syntax is anything directly after "Given a slice" in this section.

Define `<POS>` to be any positive integer, that is any digit `1-9` followed by any amount of digits `0-9`.

Define `<NEG>` to be any negative integer, that is a `-` followed by `<POS>`

Define `<INT>` to be `<POS>`, `<NEG>`, or `<ZERO>`

Define `sgn(a)` to be the sign of `a`: 1 for positive `a`, -1 for negative `a`, and 0 for `a=0`.

For all of the following, `a` and `b` are `<INT>` and `c` is `<POS>` or `<NEG>` unless otherwise specified.

- Given a slice `[]`, your program may have undefined behavior.
- Given a slice `[a]`, your program or function must return `[a:a+k:c]` for some `<POS>` or `<NEG>` value of `c` and `0 < abs(k) <= abs(c)` and (`a+k < 0` if `c < 0`) and (`a+b > 0` if `c > 0`)
- Given a slice `[:]`, your program must return `[0::1]`.
- Given a slice `[a:]`, your program must return `[a::1]`.
- Given a slice `[:b]`, your program must return `[0:b:1]`.
- Given a slice `[a:b]` where `a < b` and `sgn(a)+sgn(b) != 0` your program must return `[a:b:1]`.
- Given a slice `[::]`, your program must return `[0::1]`.
- Given a slice `[a::]`, your program must return `[a::1]`.
- Given a slice `[:b:]`, your program must return `[0:b:1]`.
- Given a slice `[::c]`, your program must return `[0::c]` if `c` is `<POS>` and `[-1::c]` otherwise.
- Given a slice `[a:b:]` where `a < b` and `sgn(a)+sgn(b) != 0`, your program must return `[a:b:1]`.
- Given a slice `[a::c]`, your program must return `[a::c]`.
- Given a slice `[:b:c]`, your program must return `[0:b:c]` if `c` is `<POS>` and `[-1:b:c]` otherwise.
- Given a slice `[a:b:c]` your program must return `[a:b:c]`.

## Example

The "slice" `[5]` gives the fifth element of an array.

Your program or function can output `[5:6:1]` or `[5:7:2]` or `[5:1000:1000]` or `[5:4:-1]` or `[5:0:-5]`.

The program **cannot** output `[5:7:1]` or `[5:-6:1]` or `[5:-6:-1]` or `[5:6:-1]`.

## Test Cases

```
Input     Output
[1]       [1:2:1]     [Output may vary]
[-1]      [-1:-2:-1]  [Output may vary]
[:]       [0::1]
[1:]      [1::1]
[-1:]     [-1::1]
[0:3]     [0:3:1]
[-3:-1]   [-3:-1:1]
[::]      [0::1]
[0::]     [0::1]
[:5:]     [0:5:1]
[::2]     [0::2]
[::-2]    [-1::-2]
[2:4:]    [2:4:1]
[2::3]    [2::3]
[:2:1]    [0:2:1]
[:2:-1]   [-1:2:-1]
[1:2:3]   [1:2:3]
```

## Rules

- You do not have to do any input validation.
- The output and input may include or exclude the brackets `[]`.
- The output and input may be a 3-tuple instead of a `:`-delimited string.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code **in each language** wins.

Comment: Did anyone else read the title in the same way you'd say "Ice, Ice, Baby!"

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That was my intention :)

Comment: Although you haven't logged on since September, I am wondering how exactly the 3-tuple I/O option is supposed to work... are blanks before/after colons represented by arbitrary non-integer elements, or does everything have to be a string? Are missing colons represented by a different arbitrary non-integer element, or can input tuples have less than three elements?

Comment: @UnrelatedString generally, I/O here is permissive, so the answer to your first question is: you can do anything that works for you. On your second question, having an tuple with less than 3 elements would be ambiguous. For example, `[a:]` and `[:b]` have different behavior despite having the same elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and welcome back! The ambiguity shouldn't be an issue with an element (I'll call it `e`) that would represent an empty slot, since `[a:]` would be `(a,e)` and `[:b]` would be `(e,b)`, so if that's the only reason not to use variable-size tuples (or nested tuples) then I'll go ahead and do it unless I can think of a more convenient encoding.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>101</s> <s>96</s> <s>90</s> <s>85</s> 82 bytes

```python
def f(r):l=len(r);b=r[l>1]+'1'*(l<2);c=(r+[0,b])[2]or'1';print r[0]or~-('.'<c),b,c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNDoMgEEb3noKNGahoBNuNfxchbLSa2hg01IXd9Op0Gi21Ccm8N/NNCMzP5TYZ6dy160lPLcvHauwMQtFUVo210BEIONGxlKxoK2ojlfJGMyX1ZHFSzHYwC7EqRX/FFBIoW8Yb3rp@smQlgyEqUJjUHEu8V@CwgfAU/zBFyvZuhnzcOma8IFyOgkceJd5NIp99UG7DzCc/DfFn35vF7pjVeUC2R4MKHxpCyCG5T4OhK8OFGniAP7ky9wY)

**Explanation:**

Basically a golfed version of:

```python
f(r):
 if len(r)==1:return [r[0],r[0]+'1',r[0]+'1']            # [a, a1, a1] where a1 is further from 0 than a
 if len(r)==2:return [r[0]or'0',r[1],'1']                # [a or 0, b, 1]
 if len(r)==3:return [r[0]or -1*(r[2]<0),r[1],r[2]or'1'] # [a or 0|-1, b, c or 1]
```

Comment: [Change `return` to `print` for 85 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZBBCoMwEEX3niIbmaQmYmK70epFQkC0Si0SJXVhT59O0VoLgXlv5g8hmV7zfbTK@1vbkY46lg3F0FqEvC6cHkppIpBwosNVsbwpqIt0wmvDtDKjw0k@ud7OxOkEvRLyRCGGsmEVr3nju9GRhfSW6EBj2HAsYqvAYQW5k/hhgpRu3RT5uHXM7IJwOQoedRSxmUI@70G1DtM9@WnIP/veLDfHrMkCsr4bdPg0EEIG8WPsLV0YLpTAA/zMhfk3)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin <s>354</s> 330 bytes

### Submission

```
fun f(i:List<Int?>):List<Int?>?{
val N=null
val Z=mutableListOf(0,N,1)
if(i.none{it!=N})return Z
val v:Int=i[0]?:0
val z:Int=if(i.size==3)i[2]?:1 else 1
val p=if(v<0)-1 else 1
return when(i.size){1->listOf(v,v+p,p)
2->listOf(v, i[1], z)
3->{if(i[0]==N&&i[2]!=N&&i[2]!!<0)Z[0]=-1
return i.zip(Z).map{it.first?:it.second}}
else->N}}
```

### Beautified

```
fun f(input: List<Int?>): List<Int?> {
    if (input.none { it != null }) return listOf(0, null, 1)
    val item0: Int = input[0] ?: 0
    val step: Int = if (input.size == 3) input[2] ?: 1 else 1
    val direction = if (item0 < 0) -1 else 1
    return when (input.size) {
        1 -> listOf(item0, item0 + direction, direction)
        2 -> {
            listOf(item0, input[1], step)
        }
        3 -> {
            val D = mutableListOf(0, null, 1)
            if (input[0] == null && input[2] != null && input[2]!! < 0) D[0] = -1
            return input.zip(D).map { it.first ?: it.second }
        }
        else -> listOf()
    }
}
```

### TryItOnline

[Link](https://tio.run/##pVXRatswFH33V9yWUiwimdheX0ydvGSDQkkL62CQ9cFr5E7MUYwtZxDjb8@upNhJTLa6myCJfHTPvcdX0snPtcqE3O3SSkLqiuhelOr2TqrphBzN602SwRxikFWWOQIDPbmWvBbqIoZ5QwquqkJChoSH1B3TOfWJozmbCPmxWIyfp9HYIFuL6BSl2HKIYwiJWAQY4APPSg6@ict1zOZ2TFgH76v8@sHlnk1qn032VTd0M8ppTpyATeoOEwv/mW5J44TMvsUsXlUq@Z7x@xOxIgVXy4zj@fW1lnPRTS5QxEwvsU6C8LYid2fEWyU5NsFLRVGqaYSzkr@s5bJpjGQ2aVtCmsZxlolK4CVLyhKeeKlm@OhqSULmlYrg0G4KGl5XqocTx9H7tEqERGKRFK@AnzKCz6oQ8pVA7QAOk1PxVYkbtq9v8HZ0xfeLPqFtnE8hoOATQv/KYEcUhhyGJPYmSx8eao7QgT22wICafp/qD6ZqiT0yG85GieGJ4HBIydB05FDPPA8gGlH/16ku8l8TmLCbM/yb971AcKZ48A4@C85tGHszBZ7GD331FvMHUG2V8ITaYkO0mwt0/OLB0K4FvTNjbyMbcjWCE8UtQAwNbUP/pOsCPQ59AQ3H@kNrGK1poOOgZaQmyDOuRLp1bZBmPTZcz7rTcQY9cvQhlUn3cjQaPaLR8WX0TeL8bg5wVR/yNgZ9@PLUojadhT9@fYQrBC7J2dwHtLH/DH@QwBj7lIjMSMD5GQmImlo9CQgbZYMkOPa72e1@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 268 bytes

```python
import re
w='([^:]*)'
def f(x):
	(a,b,c,d,e)=re.findall('\[%s(?:(:)%s(?:(:)%s)?)?\]'%(w,w,w),x)[0]
	g=int(a)if a else(-1if e and int(e)<0else 0)
	return'[%s:%s:%s]'%(g,c if c else(g+(1if g>0else-1)if not(b or d)else''),e if e else((1if g>0else-1)if not(b or d)else 1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBboMwDIbP5Sl8qWJvoSKwXaxRHoQyiZbAkFqoQqZ2qvrsXUKBHadE8hc7/x8nOf/Yr75LHo/2dO6NBaODSyow/@TihURQ6RpqvBIHKyzlXh5kJTWlRm/qtqvK4xHFLl8PmDEy/UXKKNsVYo0X6QbJK@VREayatO0sltTWUII@DhpD5VhD2VXgS5o@Ip@HiIKV0fbbdMLZ8zi9XyMP4BSHp7p5Ra9vtqMoVN646y3uoTdQkU8KQVLDeMgo@VcAiuhRu6XVg3VNAYpcFUKCyMMp8jMontMTRJxMmYSXvUttAn6fgeMZwolifuOZZi@OWS00uyrHru6/5Wz8w4lbdE@3N3UXG9f7qbTo25fu73wkd6Vf)